# Is there an example of a compact complex (Kähler) manifold of general type with trivial topological euler charcteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Topological Euler characteristic is given by the top Chern class of the tangent bundle up to sign.

Comments: Examples don't exist in dimension 2 due to Bogomolov–Miyaoka–Yau inequality. Is that true in higher dimensions? Examples are known if one assumes a weaker condition that the holomorphic Euler characteristic is zero.

Wonder after Jason Starr's answer: Is there a minimal manifold of general type with zero Euler characteristic?

Comment: A product of three hyperbolic curves of genera $g$, $g'$ and $g''$ has topological Euler characteristic equal to $-8(g-1)(g'-1)(g''-1)$.  If you blow up that threefold at $4(g-1)(g'-1)(g''-1)$ points, this appears to have topological Euler characteristic equal to $0$.

Comment: cool! so simple. Thank you very much. If you turned it into an answer I will accept it!